# Binary tree insert - java

Tags: java, insert, binary-tree

I'm trying to insert elements into binary tree, if the element is inserted it should return true and if the element is already in the tree it should return false.

Here is what i did, It doesn't give me any error message but it only returns true for the first element inserted and for the rest of them false even if they are not the same as the first element.

```
    public static class Node { 
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;
        
        Node(int d) 
        {data=d;
        left=null;
        right=null;}
        
    }
    static class BTree{
        Node root;
    }
    
    
    static boolean insert(BTree t,int data) {
        Node newNode=new Node(data);
        if (t.root==null) {
            t.root=newNode;
            return true;
        }
        
        else {
            while (t.root.data!=data) {
                if (t.root.data>data) 
                {t.root=t.root.left;  insert(t, data);}
                else if (t.root.data<data) 
                {t.root=t.root.right; insert(t, data);}}
            return false;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: If reaches `return false;` for any but the root element.

Comment: @ChristophDahlen any help on where i should put it? i'm trying to make it return false if the t.root.data==data

Comment: As you said: Return false if t.root.data == data, true in any other case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is modifying `t.root` when the tree is not empty. This is wrong. During the decent through the tree, the root reference should not be changed.

Secondly, your algorithm is using *both* iteration (`while`) and recursion. But these are alternatives that you should not *combine*: choose either the iterative version or the recursive version.

Since your function takes a `BTree` instance, and there is only one such instance at play, a recursive implementation would need a different function; one that takes a `Node` type as argument.

Here I will just stick to the iterative idea and remove the recursion. Use a separate variable for traversing down the tree:

```
        else {
            Node node = t.root;
            while (node.data != data) {
                if (node.data > data) {
                    if (node.left == null) {
                        node.left = newNode;
                        return true;
                    }
                    node = node.left;
                } else if (node.data < data) {
                    if (node.right == null) {
                        node.right = newNode;
                        return true;
                    }
                    node = node.right;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```